# Create a Hyperlink after including the value of a cell to an existing Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, hyperlink

In Excel, I have a numerical value in a cell, eg. 52123212 in C2.
I concat the hyperlink and numerical value, i.e, "https://www.getinfoo.com/"&C2 and place it in D2.
Now I create a hyperlink of D2 i.e, =hyperlink("D2") and place it in E2. This works.
But the user can modify or delete the cell namely E2.
I want to assign this hyperlink to a macro or command button, so that the user does not delete or modify, once the worksheet is protected.
Kindly Help.

Comment: Did you protect the sheet against editing?

Comment: Could you be more specific? In your context, I'm not sure what *"assign this hyperlink"* means. Maybe think about when should something happen, and when it shouldn't.

Comment: Sir I searched for the same and got the answer and resolved the same. Thank you.